# Return 0 Values for each user

Tags: sql

I want to pull 0 values however my query doesn't allow for 0 values and it takes long to execute.

Here is my code:

```
select a.Owner_Id,
b.Name as KPI,
B.Record_Type,
B.Resource_Id,
C.Display_Name,
count(*) as Max

from amgr_appointments A
right outer join AMGR_Resources B on A.Owner_Id = b.Resource_Id
right outer JOIN ADMN_User_Details AS C ON A.Creator_Id=C.User_Id

where b.Resource_Id in ('ROE534B758E', 'R0E42A431B5', 'R0E42A4BB3F','R0E42A3E514','R0E42A44D19', 'R0E42A37FBB')
and b.Record_Type = 3
and a.Creator_Id In('AMCKENZIE','ASARAK', 'JMALAN')
and A.App_Date between '2016-02-29'and '2016-03-29'
Group by a.Owner_Id, a.Creator_Id, b.Name, B.Record_Type, B.Resource_Id, c.Display_Name
```

I get the following results:

```
amckenzie 1 Pop-in
ASARAK    2 Pop-in
```

However I want this result that includes the user even if the value is 0

```
amckenzie 1 Pop-in
ASARAK    2 Pop-in
JMALAN    0 Pop-in
```

Please help me and show me where im going wrong. I have tried different joins however the query runs too long

Comment: Sample data for all the tables would really help, for which you are getting this output.  Also mention the DB/Version which you would be using

Comment: i guess you wanna show count(*) can be 0. If so, can you try IFNULL(count(*),0).

Comment: the IFNULL(count(),0). shows 0 for all rows, I want the value 0 to be returned if the user has no appointments

Comment: it seems the group by statement is killing some of the users. if run the queries separate select statements without the group by, it returns all rows. can I maybe use a union all? how would this affect the query or preformance

Answer (score 0):

Try as below

```
 SELECT a.Owner_Id,
           b.Name as KPI,
           B.Record_Type,
           B.Resource_Id,
           C.Display_Name,
           count(*) as Max
    FROM amgr_appointments A
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN AMGR_Resources B 
       ON (A.Owner_Id = b.Resource_Id
       AND a.Creator_Id In('AMCKENZIE','ASARAK', 'JMALAN')
       AND A.App_Date BETWEEN '2016-02-29'AND '2016-03-29')
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN ADMN_User_Details AS C 
       ON (A.Creator_Id = C.User_Id)
    WHERE b.Resource_Id in ('ROE534B758E', 'R0E42A431B5', 'R0E42A4BB3F','R0E42A3E514','R0E42A44D19', 'R0E42A37FBB')
       AND b.Record_Type = 3
    GROUP BY a.Owner_Id, a.Creator_Id, b.Name, B.Record_Type, B.Resource_Id, c.Display_Name
```